# /bin/sh: passwd: command not found

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I tried to execute Docker-compose build but getting the below error.

I'm using centos7 and completely new to Linux.

```
/bin/sh: passwd: command not found.
ERROR: Service 'remote_host' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c useradd remote_user &&     echo "welcome1" | passwd remote_user --stdin &&     mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh &&     chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh' returned a non-zero code: 127.
```

DockerFile.

```
FROM centos: latest
RUN yum -y install OpenSSH-server

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "welcome1" | passwd remote_user --stdin && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh`enter code here`

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

whoami: mosses987
$PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/mosses987/.local/bin:/home/mosses987/bin

Comment: It's not pre-installed. If you run `docker container run --rm -it centos` you can check what's in `/usr/bin` (`ls -l /usr/bin`).

Comment: The sh is present in /usr/bin
[root@df322206d5a6 bin]# sh
sh-4.4#

Comment: `sh` is but `passwd` isn't. Your error is `passwd: command not found`.

Comment: It has passwd also
[mosses987@localhost bin]$ find -L /bin/ -name "passwd"
/bin/passwd

Comment: Are you searching in container or on your local machine?

Comment: I'm checking in my local machine

Comment: Well, that's the problem. Everything is happening in the container. `centos` image doesn't have `passwd` installed.

Comment: How can I resolve this problem. I'm completely new to these concepts

Comment: Install everything you need (`yum install -y passwd`). You can imagine Docker containers as lightweight Linux machines, so you can apply your Linux knowledge when setting up container.

Comment: See I'm using windows machine
Where I use virtual box to install Centos7
In Centos I have passwd already installed
But the docker image in Centos I don't see passwd installed

Comment: Then it's an opportunity to expand your Linux knowledge :)

Comment: See I'm using windows machine Where I use virtual box to install Centos7 In Centos I have passwd already installed But the docker image in Centos I don't see passwd installed

Comment: That's because maintainers are constantly working on reducing image size, so they analyze common use-cases and remove unnecessary tools. And that's why you don't have `passwd` or `which` inside CentOS container. But, as I said, you can install whatever you need, just as you would inside VM.

Comment: I tried but inside docker image yum is not working
centos has passwd, vi which etc

Comment: /bin/sh: /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen: No such file or directory
how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 8):

add this line its working:

```
RUN yum install -y passwd
```

And comment this line:

```
RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work,

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y install openssh-server

RUN yum install -y passwd

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "1234" | passwd remote_user --stdin && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

#RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `passwd` because the remote host does not have `passwd installed`. Add below line before the `passwd` command.

```
RUN yum install -y passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line

RUN yum install -y  passwd

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
FROM centos:7


RUN yum update -y && \
    yum -y install openssh-server && \
    yum install -y passwd


RUN useradd remote_user  && \
    echo "1234" | passwd remote_user --stdin && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh


COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys


RUN chown -R remote_user:remote_user /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod -R 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys


RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen


CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same file, I faced the same issue but resolved it with a post [written by Jaimil Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62315994)
but a new error occur about **ssh_host_rsa_key** not being found so I resolved the error by adding the block bellow

```
RUN  ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key && \
     ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key && \
     ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key && \
     ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

New error when you try to login with ssh to remote container

`System is booting up. Unprivileged users are not permitted to log in yet. Please come back later. For technical details, see pam_nologin(8).`

So I resolve this error by adding

`rm /run/nologin`

**Updated version of the dockerfile**

```
FROM centos

RUN cd /etc/yum.repos.d/ && \
 sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-* && \
 sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

RUN yum -y install openssh-server passwd

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "1234" | passwd remote_user  --stdin && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh


RUN  ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key && \
     ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key && \
     ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key && \
     ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user   -R /home/remote_user && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
    rm /run/nologin



CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```